# See Excel add-in via Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, add-in

How can I retrieve a constant (or other items) from an Excel add-in via Access VBA? I am using Office 2013. I can open an Excel instance, and it shows the add-in as installed, but I do not know how to refer to the modules (for which I have the password) or items within the modules (e.g., a constant). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a function in the Add In would be the easiest way

```
public function GET_CONST_CONSTANTNAME() as variant
     GET_CONST_CONSTANTNAME=cstApplicationVersion
end function
```

other way is to start exploring with the IDE, looking for declaration lines etc.  can be time consuming